# Html tag for uploading swf format video

Tags: html

I am using **swf format video** for displaying on html page.
When the page loads on `IPAD`, it displays blank space.
How should I generate an `error message when it opens on IPAD.`

Comment: No, I wouldn't have thought so. We will need to see some code at the very least...

Answer (score 2):

use SWFObject to load the Flash movie, this will allow you to display messages if the page is being viewed on a device that cannot display Flash.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/